# Влияние нашествия монголов на русский язык

Tags: этимология, лексика, выбор-слов

Как повлияло *татаро-монгольское иго 13-15 веков* на словарь русского языка?
Какими монгольскими словами мы пользуемся до сих пор?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Непосредственно монгольских слов в русском языке почти нет, да и те что есть — не факт, что от монголов, а не от тюрков, у которых есть похожие слова. В качестве примера таких слов можно назвать: *ярлык, тумен, ямщик и пр.*

Сказать, что монголов в Орде не было, нельзя: тот же Бату-хан (Батый) был официальным потомком Чингисхана (кровное родство спорно), но нужно понимать, что само нашествие было скоротечным, да и в дальнейшем представители Орды наведывались нечасто, к тому же и в самой Золотой Орде монголов было немного, поэтому монгольских слов почти и не осталось. С тюркоязычными же народами (печенеги, половцы, татары) мы общались и до и после Ига, поэтому утверждать, что слово появилось в русском языке именно из-за него, чаще всего невозможно.

Что касается наличия самого Ига, то это дискуссионный вопрос. Статус Руси был примерно такой же, как у современных стран Британского содружества, где Англия - аналог Орды (в разные периоды Ига зависимость усиливалась или ослабевала, но в целом близкая аналогия).

Любителям же Фоменко советую изучить, до какого года идет непрерывная линия дендрохронологии и как найденные артефакты вписываются в изыскания этого ученого.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78484/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 4):

Термин "монгольское (монголо-татарское) иго" ввел Карамзин. За что, кстати, нередко подвергался критике за тенденциозность - и, надо сказать, не без оснований. Завоеватели представляли из себя достаточно разнородную общность, но монголов в современном понимании там не было.

Монгольские языки очень далеки от тюркских, пусть никого не смущает, что обе группы в ходят в алтайскую [макро]семью, японский в неё тоже входит.

Остальное - у Fuchoin Kazuki.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78485/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus------).

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут уместнее говорить не о монгольских, а о тюркских корнях в русском языке.
Собственно, тут можно писать целую научную работу, а если коротко, то тюркских слов у нас просто полно. Ну, навскидку, то, что приходит в голову: алтын (монета, в переводе "золото"), башка (голова), кабак (с тюркского "тыква"), колпак и т.д. Я уж не говорю о множестве тюркских фамилий, ставших русскими, таких как Юсупов, Тургенев, Кирсанов и т.д.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78486/discussion-on-answer-by-fuchoin-kazuki------).

Answer (score 0):

Правильно говорить не монгольскими, а тюркскими.
Вот цитата из книги Казимира Валишевского  - "Иван Грозный"

> "Взгляните на москвича XVI века: он,
> кажется, с ног до головы одет
> по-самаркандски. Башмак, азям, армяк,
> зипун, чебыги, кафтан, очкур, шлык,
> башлык, колпак, клобук, тафья, темляк
> — таковы татарские названия различных
> предметов его одеяния. Если,
> поссорившись с товарищем, он станет
> ругаться, в его репертуаре неизменно
> будет фигурировать "дурак", а если
> придется драться, в дело пойдет
> "кулак". Будучи судьей, он наденет на
> подсудимого "кандалы" и позовет "ката"
> дать осужденному "кнута". Будучи
> правителем, он собирает налоги в
> "казну", охраняемую "караулом" и
> устраивает по дорогам станции,
> называемые "ямами", которые
> обслуживаются "ямщиками". Наконец,
> встав из почтовых саней, он заходит в
> "кабак", заменивший собой древнюю
> русскую корчму. И все эти слова
> азиатского происхождения."

Comment: Несомненно, монголов нам приписали Романовы вместе с западно-европейскими историками и политиками. Слишком много накопилось тому свидетельств, чтобы пытаться это отрицать. А вот татары на Руси были всегда. Они составляли основу так называемой русской воинской Орды. Были, конечно и другие народы, защищающие рубежи Руси и расширяющие ее, и все они составляли казачьи дружины. Татары, например, осваивали многие земли Северной Америки, Европы и Африки.

Comment: "Правильно говорить не монгольскими, а тюркскими." - в каком-то смысле - да. Тут некая путаница. Но переворачивать сложившуюся терминологию - тоже не комильфо. А главное: какое это всё отношение имеет непосредственно к вопросу?

Comment: "Дурак", "кулак", "клобук" - слова славянского происхождения. "Кнут" - в славянские языки попало из скандинавских языков. "Кабак" - из немецкого.

Answer (score -1):

Башка - это русифицированное тюркское слово баш (баши) - вершина горы. Посмотрите на карты горных республик и убедитесь. Этим верховенством тюрки наделяли начальников: Кайрам-баши, курбаши, Баши-Бузука и пр. Башкой русские назвали верхушку тела, где окончание ка "уменьшает" корень до размера головы.

В своей работе "Другая история Руси" С Валянский и В Калюжный вывели слово орда от западноевропейского ордена. Согласно их аргументации Русь подвергалась постоянному давлению с запада, а вовсе не с востока, поэтому никакого влияния на русский язык "официальная" Орда не имела. Другое дело, что тюркские слова были заимствованы в сфере торговых, политических и др. отношений.

Кстати, о монгольских лошадках. Десятки тысяч их гибли на нашей территории. Кто-нибудь натыкался на их кости? Десятки тысяч должны были затеряться в лесах и полях Руси. Они должны были оставить свои хромосомы в нынешнем поколении российских лошадушек. Подтверждают ли это научные исследования? Я не знаю, я не читал. А кто читал? Так на чем могли прискакать к нам монголы и оказать влияние на русский язык?

Comment: напрасный труд,  о́рден в знач. "знак отличия", у Петра I; см. Смирнов 212. Заимств. из нем. Orden, первонач. "сословие", ср.-в.-н. оrdеn от лат. ordō, -inis "ряд, порядок".  Это по Фасмеру.
А по жижни  в Риме  Никто зерна не выращивал, его импортировали и в ряду стоял обычный ячмень-hordei, а орда-по латински-horde, равно как в немецком и датском.
в общем-  гордеи-и по греческому толкованию -цари. а в датском еще и гидроним в качестве уточнения в названии Ячменя--откуда везли--byg med да впридачу еще кой чего, в виде второго корня.

Comment: да, на русь давили, именно с запада, поэтому с запада основное влияние языковое и перло, но это после того как ее с запада и выдавили. Германии как таковой и не было, а вплоть до рейна остались русские топонимы.

Answer (score -3):

Москва- мушгиа крутящий 
Ура - хураая захватываем
Кремль - хэрэм стена крепость
Арбат- аравт арабт десяток 
Телега - тэрэг телега
Тюрем - түрэм дүрэм

И так далее ... Монголское слово, название  очень много

Comment: Амур — из той же оперы?